# Unable to connect to ADAM with Windows domain\username

Tags: web-config, adam, authentication, activedirectorymembership

I'm having some difficulty connecting to an ADAM instance from my Commerce Server 2007 ASP .NET solution, and I believe it relates to my config file somehow.  The short version is that I can connect to ADAM through ADAM-ADSIEdit with my current username/password, but when I put  this in my web.config i get "Parser Error Message: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LDAPConnection" connectionString="LDAP://<domain/>:389/<Partition DN>" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="MembershipADAMProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MembershipADAMProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        connectionStringName="LDAPConnection"
        connectionProtection="None" 
        connectionUsername="<domain>\<username>"
        connectionPassword="<password>"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I've tried a bunch of things to fix this and haven't come up with any kind of reasonable solution.  I started with just the connection String and no username or password.  I got an error saying that I could not make a secure connection.  that's when I added the connectionProtection="None" line.  Then it said I could not use default credentials without a secure connection, so I added the Username and Password fields.  When I created the ADAM instance, I used the current Windows login credentials.  I've tried to use my windows login credentials here in web.config, and I've tried with various domain names, pretty much anything I could think of.  I'm totally lost why I cant bind with ldp and I can connect in ASIEdit with these domain\username and password but can't from my CommerceServer ASP .NET application...Is there some other step I'm missing?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Also, I tried <identity impersonate="true"/> with the same username/password combinations, and that did not seem to help either as I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the information [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150628074151/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dansellers/archive/2005/10/11/479941.aspx), there is a lot of good stuff about secure connections and how to disable them within your ADAM instance for development purposes.